# How to populate aspx:TextBox with SqlDataSource as we can in aspx:DropDown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I need to populate a text box using some queries. I an newbie in asp.net, whereas i was able to do that with `asp:DropDown`. How should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Page.DataBind()` to bind public properties with your page.

```
<asp:textbox id=txt text="<%# custID %>" runat=server />
```

Refer the [databinding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

> ASP.NET introduces a new declarative syntax, <%# %>. This syntax is
>   the basis for using data binding in an .aspx page. All data binding
>   expressions must be contained within these characters.
>
> No data is rendered to the control until you explicitly call either
>   the DataBind method of the Web server control or until you invoke the
>   page-level Page.DataBind method. Typically, Page.DataBind (or
>   DataBind) is called from the Page_Load event.